# Location of C standard library

Tags: c, gcc

In the gcc manual it is given that "The C standard library itself
is stored in ‘/usr/lib/libc.a’". I have gcc installed, but could not find libc.a at the said location. Curious to know where is it located.

I find many .so files in /usr/lib location. What are those?

Comment: Did you try asking your package manager?

Comment: I know this an old question, but the current gcc documentation (7.3.0 and 8.2.0) doesn't have that wording. On some Unix-like systems, you can compile and link a simple program and run `ldd` on the  executable.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A few things:

- gcc and glibc are two different things. gcc is the compiler, glibc are the runtime libraries. Pretty much everything needs glibc to run.
- `.a` files are static libraries, `.so` means shared object and is the Linux equivalent of a DLL
- Most things DON'T link against libc.a, they link against libc.so

Hope that clears it up for you. As for the location, it's almost certainly going to be in `/usr/lib/libc.a` and / or `/usr/lib/libc.so`. Like I said, the .so one is the more common.

Comment: Is libc.so dynamically linked and libc.a statically linked?

Comment: libc.so and libc.a both provide the same functionality. The difference is that if you link against libc.so, whenever libc.so gets upgraded your program gets the benefit of the upgrade with no changes. However if you link against libc.a all of the functionality is packaged into your program. New updates to libc won't update your program, so it will have to be recompiled.

Comment: So yes, .so is the dynamically linked one, and .a is the statically linked one.

Answer (score 57):

If you are looking for `libc.a`:

```
$ gcc --print-file-name=libc.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a
```

Comment: This is the most correct answer by far - uses a standard tool to find the location of libc which is *not* standard in any way (as I have found out).

Answer (score 9):

If you are on RPM based Linux (Red Hat/CentOS/Fedora/SUSE) then you would get the location of the installed glibc with
`rpm -ql glibc` and `rpm -ql glibc-devel` .

`locate libc.a` would get you the location. And to see from where it comes do:
`rpm -qf /usr/lib/libc.a`

Here is what `rpm -qi` has to tell about these packages

glibc-devel:

> The glibc-devel package contains the object files necessary
>   for developing programs which use the standard C libraries (which are
>   used by nearly all programs).  If you are developing programs which
>   will use the standard C libraries, your system needs to have these
>   standard object files available in order to create the
>   executables.
>   Install glibc-devel if you are going to develop programs which will
>   use the standard C libraries

glibc:

> The glibc package contains standard libraries which are used by
>   multiple programs on the system. In order to save disk space and
>   memory, as well as to make upgrading easier, common system code is
>   kept in one place and shared between programs. This particular package
>   contains the most important sets of shared libraries: the standard C
>   library and the standard math library. Without these two libraries, a
>   Linux system will not function.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install package for static libraries separately:
glibc-static.i686

Answer (score 2):

On centos 5.8

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/libc.a
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2442786 Apr  8  2010 /usr/lib/libc.a

$ rpm -qf /usr/lib/libc.a
glibc-devel-2.3.4-2.43.el4_8.3
```

You also have to have the `glibc-devel` package install under RedHat distributions.