# Where are the functions in the C standard library defined?

Tags: c, standard-library

I'm not interested in the source code, I want to know how the C compiler (GCC) actually finds the functions. As in, when the preprocessor sees that I've included `stdio.h`, where does it look to find the files that define the function bodies?

**Edit**

I should probably also say I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, but if there's a general answer, that would work too.

Comment: The *compiler* only needs the header files. The *linker*, however, needs object or library files.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481154/default-libraries-linked-in-by-gcc

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`gcc` comes with (binary) object files (*not* C source files) which contain implementations of all the standard C functions. When you use `gcc` to link object files into an executable file, the linker *automatically* includes the object files which implement the standard library functions. According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925678/location-of-c-standard-library), that standard object file will probably be called `libc.a` or `libc.so`.

Say you include a call to `printf` in your program. When the linker tries to resolve where that call should go, it will find the definition of `printf` in `libc.a`, and make your function call point there.

Look at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html and note the `-nostdlib` and `-nodefaultlibs` options. You can use these options to tell `gcc`'s linker *not* to include the standard library object files by default.

Comment: So does the linker automatically include object files that implement *all* the standard library functions every time? If so, what's the point of associating different functions with different header files, if they all get included anyway?

Comment: The *object files* are used by the `gcc` *linker*. The *header files* are used by the *compiler*. The compiler needs to see the headers, so it knows the function signatures and thus 1) can type-check the code, and 2) can generate the right code for passing arguments and getting the return value. Why didn't they put the signatures for *all* the standard library functions in a single header file? Well, for one thing, it would be non-compliant with the C standard, since the C standard actually defines what the standard header files should be. For another thing, it would make compile times slower.

Comment: Also, @Tyler, the linker doesn't include object files from a static library unless they are needed. The .a file is an indexed library of separate object modules, and the linker will include only those that resolve an undefined symbol (and some of those may reference new undefined symbols, so it will keep going). In the case of a .so, the whole library will be loaded at runtime, so this does not apply.

Answer (score 13):

`gcc` obtains the *function definitions* from the C library.  You could determine the path that `gcc` would look into, by default, for it by saying:

```
ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR
```

This leads to `/usr/lib` on my system.

Lets try to find if the library contains the symbol for a standard function, say `scanf`:

```
nm -A /usr/lib/libc.so | grep scanf
```

The results include:

```
/lib/libc.so:0000000000042a90 T scanf
```

---

Consider a small example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Lets call it `i.c`:

```
$ gcc i.c              # Compile
$ ldd ./a.out          # Try to find dependencies
./a.out:
        -lc.12 => /usr/lib/libc.so.12
```

The last command essentially implies that the binary depends upon `/usr/lib/libc.so.12`
 and that you'd find the definitions of the functions used in the code therein.

Answer (score 4):

Your question has to do with where GCC searches for header files. It searches the standard include directories. You may find [this thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/where-standard-system-include-directory-is-defined-gcc-466068/) to be useful:

> With various options (such as -I and -I- and -isystem) you can specify
>   lots of different inclusion features. Basically, directories specified
>   by -I will be searched before those specified by -isystem, which will
>   in turn be searched before those in the "standard system include
>   directories" (at least, according to my tests). The difference is that
>   -I can be used for any #include directive, but -isystem will only be used for #include <...> That said, though, it is recommended to only
>   use -I for #include "..." directives because of the search order.
>   Using -I- really gives you a lot of control because any -I used before
>   -I- will be searched for only for #include "..." whilst any -I used after -I- will be searched for any #include directive. In addition,
>   using -I- means that the current directory will not be searched for
>   included files unless you also specify -I. (search the current
>   directory).
>
> If you want to get a listing of what search directories are supported
>   by default, try running this command: `cpp -v < /dev/null` This runs
>   the GNU C Preprocessor with no input; in the process it will print
>   (given the -v flag) the inclusion directory search paths. You should
>   see phrases like "#include <...> search starts here:" followed by a
>   list of directories. Those are your standard inclusion search paths,
>   in the order that they're searched.

Comment: This is somewhat tangential to where the libraries are found, though if the headers are found by default in `/some/path/include`, the libraries are usually found in `/some/path/lib`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `libc` (or `libstdc++` for C++) might be located in either `/usr/lib` or `/usr/lib64` on Linux. These are **shared libraries** and you can modify the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable to specify what directories they're searched in. A practical example would be you install a local copy of gcc and chances are it will have an updated version of the standard library as opposed to your system, so you would want your local gcc to start up with that instead, i.e `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/local-install/gcc/lib64`

Comment: The C compiler is unlikely to need libstdc++.

Comment: @BrianDrummond: Yes, probably a typo. I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks into the library paths set by the environment variable.

Read more: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html

Comment: He's not asking where `gcc` finds the standard headers. He's asking where it finds the *bodies* of those functions.