# How to find location of C header file errno.h on macOS?

Tags: c, macos, header-files, macos-catalina, errno

I am new to C language and am trying to view the source for the header file [`errno.h`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/errno.h.html).

How can I:

1. Figure out where the header file is stored on my computer?
2. View the source of the header file?

**What I've Tried**

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36103882/11163122), running `gcc --print-file-name=errno.h` in my `$HOME` directory just outputs `errno.h`.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/503920/11163122), running `cpp -dM /usr/include/errno.h | grep 'define E' | sort -n -k 3` outputs:

```sh
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/include/errno.h'
clang: error: no input files
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65866788/11163122), running `clang -E /usr/include/errno.h` outputs:

```sh
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/include/errno.h'
clang: error: no input files
```

One solution I know works is running `sudo find / -name "errno*.h" -type f`.  However, this returns **many** results.  I am wondering if there's some programmatic way to find the source using a C-related tool (e.g. by invoking `gcc`).

**My Computer**

- macOS version: 10.15.7 (Catalina)
- `clang --version` --> `Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)`

Comment: Header files are typically stored in /usr/include.

Comment: Note that this is not a library but an include file.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the distinction, thank you @Rob.  I've updated the question

Comment: With a genuine [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler you could use the `-H` option

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - huh. learn something new each day!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do here - since `<errno.h>` is a standard library header, you will find it in: `/usr/include/errno.h`
**... Edit - I can see your issue with Catalina now. See below:**

At least on my (older) OSX box, this header isn't very informative - including `<sys/errno.h>` in turn, which does at least provide the symbolic constants: `EPERM, ENOENT, ...` (see: `man intro` for an overview)

As `<sys/errno.h>` itself includes further system headers, albeit headers that rarely concern user-space development, you can get an overview of how the compiler recursively finds these headers using the preprocessing stage:

`clang -E /usr/include/errno.h` - this works for `gcc` too.

---

For **Catalina**, the headers are now located under the SDK. I'm sure there are reasons for this - multiple SDKs (e.g., iphone development, etc), and some post-hoc rationale for security preventing the creation of a `/usr/include` directory. In any case, for Catalina, you need the Xcode tool: `xcrun` (see: `man xcrun`) to find the SDK path to: `.../usr/include`

```
`xcrun --show-sdk-path`/usr/include
```

provides the path, so to view `<errno.h>` :

```
less `xcrun --show-sdk-path`/usr/include/errno.h
```

and consequently, you can run the preprocessor with:

```
clang -E `xcrun --show-sdk-path`/usr/include/errno.h
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @BrettHale, running the `clang` command returns `error: no such file or directory: '/usr/include/errno.h'`.  Any ideas?

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer - sorry, things have changed with Catalina, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Your answer was spot on, thank you @BrettHale for updating it! :). I was able to figure out how `errno` was implemented now.